# machine.config file update crashing the website asp.net

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, load-balancing, asp.net, web.config

We are using load balancing and have three servers for that. On one of the servers the machine.config file had different machine key then the other two machines. Once we updated the machine key and made the value same as the other two, now we can't run the website through that server. What do you guys think can be the reason? Thanks, Laziale

Comment: "now we can't run the website through that server" - any error messages? error codes? please describe the behavior you expect and the behavior you are observing after the change

Comment: @MathiasR.Jesson I am getting this error message Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. I can call the website from the other two servers normally. No error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 503 usually indicates that the Application Pool is unavailable for request processing.

1. Make sure the Application Pool is running
2. Enable [Detailed Errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx) - but only for local requests, and then browse the web app from the server itself
3. If that doesn't yield any results, enable [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/), browse the site again, and review the Failed request  reports

Comment: Application Pool was stopped for some reason. Thanks